# Hotel results are not showing via api call in Amadeus

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amadeus

I have used Amadeus self-service API to build a hotel booking app.
The City/airport search is working fine. The Date filter is also working.

The only problem is Hotels results are not showing or empty Results are showing.

I am not getting what mistake I have done. Any help will be appreciated.

**Edits:**

I have put an console.log here, I can see the cityCode, checkInDate and checkoutdate but can't see the response in the console.

```
// Querying hotels
router.get(`/${API}/hotels`, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { cityCode, checkInDate, checkOutDate } = req.query;
    console.log(cityCode, checkInDate, checkOutDate);
    const response = await amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get({
      cityCode,
      checkInDate,
      checkOutDate,
    });
    consloe.log(response);
    await res.json(JSON.parse(response.body));
  } catch (err) {
    await res.json(err);
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: you have to share the code for the api call and component

Comment: Also the react code where you make the api call. In the backend when your Amadeus api is called, are you getting expected response?

Comment: Have you tested in cURL or Postman the API calls to see what exactly is returned by the API? If you use the test environment it might be the case that results are not returned since this environment has a subset of the full data.